# How can I @Required in a parent class only

Tags: java, spring

Currently I am requiring a dependency in a parent class by a setter method. when Spring initialises, I get an error that a child class (extending) requires the dependency and I must set it in the xml

Is there a way to stop this so that I only require it in the parent, then use it in inhering classes without having to do the following code in every child class

```
@Required
public setSomeClass(SomeClass someClass){
   this.someClass = someClass;
}
```